# How to create space in Bluemix

Tags: hadoop, ibm-cloud

Can anyone tell me how to create space in Bluemix and how much space is required for Hadoop?

In the Bluemix catalog, when i click on Biginsights for Apache Hadoop. it gives me the following error:

```
BXNUI0116E: The 'my mail id' organization has no spaces for which you are a developer. 
Try to select another organization or create a space.
```

Answer (score 2):

A space here is a cloud foundry concept. Quoting cloud foundry documentation: " space provides a set of users access to a shared location for application development, deployment, and maintenance. Each space role applies only to a particular space"

You don't assign a size for a space.

To create a space you need the CF command line, then run the following:

```
cf create-space <space_name> -o <organization_name>
```

You can read more about spaces here:

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/acctmgmt/index.html